# I keep getting [omitting some output] when printing Excel column with python

Tags: python

I am new to python and trying to write some code using Excel and python.

I want to print an excel column, I've imported the file but then when I print the column it starts printing but then it stops sometimes and says:

> omitting some output

However this doesn't happen all the time, sometimes I will run my code and it will print everything and sometimes it says that. I don't know what that means or how to fix it.

If it helps the excel file is very big it has about 5500 rows.

Here is my code, please help.

```
import openpyxl 
# importing the excel file
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Example.xlsx')
# getting the first sheet
name = wb.get_sheet_names()
sheet_name = name[0]
# creating the first sheet object
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheet_name) 
# print every value from column R
for row in sheet.columns[17]: 
    print(row.value)
    print('---END OF COMMENT---')
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's even an issue with blank cells. The problem is that you're trying to print all of this to the console, which has a set buffer limit and won't continue printing data over a certain size. If you want a full accounting of everything, you need to print to a text file.

Comment: But then why is it that sometimes it will print everything and sometimes it will give me [omitting some output]?

Comment: Does the size of your output change? Or are you running the same code on the same data and getting different results?

Answer (score 0):

```
if  row.value :
     print row.value
```

will solve your problem. Because there may be empty cell in in column 17 in one of the 5500 rows.

But neither I believe using openpyxl library is right way to learn python, nor I believe you are doing it for learning.

Comment: The thing is when there is an empty cell it will print none, it does that already it just stops. Also i just wanted to learn how to import excel to python and openpyxl was the software i found that gave me a simple enough tutorial if you have any others in mind do you mind sharing?